# Number Vs Varchar2 in Where Clause for performance

Tags: mysql, oracle

I have a table with `STATUS` column of `VARCHAR2(25)` and `STATE` column of `VARCHAR2(2)` along with few more columns.

While filtering records from the table, I'm using STATUS column as well as STATE column in my query.

`SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE STATUS = 'Active' AND STATE = 'WA';`

Since `STATUS` and `STATE` columns are `VARCHAR2` datatype, I would like to introduce new two columns `STATUS_ID` and `STATUS_ID` in the table with datatype as `NUMBER`. `STATUS` and `STATE` values are substituted with `NUMERIC` value for `STATUS_ID` and `STATE_ID`. So that I can use `NUMBER` column instead of `VARCHAR2` column in `WHERE` clause.

`SELECT * FROM TAB WHERE STATUS_ID = 1 AND STATE_ID = 2;`

I'm comparing `NUMBER` vs `NUMBER` and `VARCHAR2` vs `VARCHAR2` datatype only. There is no implicit or explicit conversion of datatypes exists in the query.

Will there be performance improvement of having `NUMBER` datatype instead of `VARCHAR2` in `WHERE` clause in Oracle Database?

I would like to know whether `NUMBER` datatype will have high performance over `VARCHAR2` datatype in WHERE clause. Is it true?

Thanks.

Comment: Why not test it yourself and find out?

Comment: Without adding indexes, adding two columns won't help, you'll just make each row a few bytes longer and take more time to read from the disk.  Replacing the columns entirely (add the two new ones and remove the old two) will help slightly, as now the rows will be many bytes shorter, and take less time to read from the disk. Indexing will help massively, allowing you to avoid reading irrelevant rows all together. Replacing the columns AND indexing will help a little more too, by reducing the size of the index data structure (also held on disk).  You should experiment and see.

Comment: Yes, I have composite Index on these columns appropriately but I would like to know replacing VARCHAR2 columns with NUMBER datatype will improve performance or not. Since these two VARCHAR2 columns are not longer length columns. What is the recommendation for this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Performance will be the same, since Oracle stores numbers as packed strings (unlike some other databases). Only thing you should consider before choosing format is the operations you are going to use with the value, amount of computing power thats going to be needed to convert or lookup values.

Comment: Thank you. Is it depends on the number of bytes the character column holds? As long as the Character column (size in bytes) does not exceed the size of the Number, Performance will be same. Is my understanding correct? For longer length character column, I could find the performance improvement say for example Customer Name with Customer Id.